# Netsed XML File to Python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing

I have XML file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DXGHFuM_48oSPpUDrqz3DxfyzvAgzOTD/view, want to convert to Dataframe

I have written below script to convert child/sub child to dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML_File_Path = r"Local File Path"

# Create element tree object 
Tree = ET.parse(XML_File_Path)

# Get root element 
Root = Tree.getroot()

def Root_DF(Node, Order):
    DF = pd.DataFrame([Node.attrib])
    DF['Order'] = Order
    return DF

Node_DF = pd.DataFrame()
Order = 1
for Node in Root[1]:
    Node_DF = Node_DF.append(Root_DF(Node, Order), sort=True)
    Order +=1

    for Node_C1 in Node:
    Node_DF = Node_DF.append(Root_DF(Node_C1, Order), sort=True)
    Order +=1

        for Node_C2 in Node_C1:
            Node_DF = Node_DF.append(Root_DF(Node_C2, Order), sort=True)
            Order +=1
```

But there are nested/deep sub child exist, how to simplify the script to convert all nested tags to dataframe?
Writing For Loop for Each Child is not smart way, please help us on this.
I expect code should work for any level.

Comment: You'll have to post the xml code (or at least a representative part) for someone to give you a meaningful advice.